# Почему возвращаемый с сервера массив игнорируется типами, которые я для него сделал? TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть интерфейс

```
export interface IPosts{
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body :number 
  }
```

С сервера я получаю массив:

```
{id:1, title:"alex", body: "jfk"},
{id:2, title:"daniil", body: "jfk"},
{id:3, title:"sergey", body: "jfk"},
{id:4, title:"butilka", body: "jfk"}
```

Я хочу убедиться, что запрос не вернет данные с неправильным типом(в моем случае body, т.к тип должен быть string)

[Делаю запрос с помощью axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srC5n.png)

В результате я получаю массив как ни в чем не бывало:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, почему игнорируются, установленные мной типы?

Comment: Так тайп скрипт работает только при разработке. Он статичен.

Answer (score 1):

`TypeScript` не запускается в браузере напрямую. Он сначала компилируется в самый обычный `JavaScript` и вот с ним уже работает браузер. А потому наличие или отсутствие каких либо полей вам нужно проверять вручную